# Scraping a table from html using python and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, google-colaboratory

I am trying to scrape data from a table in a government website, I have tried to watch some tutorials but so far to no avail (coding dummy over here!!!)
I would like to get a .csv file out of the tables they have containing the date, the type of event, and the adopted measures for a project. I leave here the website if any of you wants to crack it!
https://www.inspq.qc.ca/covid-19/donnees/ligne-du-temps

```
!pip install  beautifulsoup4
!pip install  requests
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 

url= "https://www.inspq.qc.ca/covid-19/donnees/ligne-du-temps"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

FIRST_table = soup.find('table', class_ = 'tableau-timeline')
print(FIRST_table)

for timeline in FIRST_table.find_all('tbody'):
  rows= timeline.find_all('tr')
  for row in rows:
    pl_timeline = row.find('td', class_ = 'date').text
    print(pl_timeline)


p
```

I was expecting to get in order the dates and to use the same for loop to get the also the other two columns by tweaking it for  "Type d'événement" and "Mesures adoptées"
What am I doing wrong? How can I tweak it? (I am using colab if it makes any difference) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easier and just use `pandas` to parse the tables and dump the data to a `.csv` file.

For example, this gets you all the tables, merges them, and spits out a `.csv` file:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://www.inspq.qc.ca/covid-19/donnees/ligne-du-temps"
tables = pd.read_html(requests.get(url).text, flavor="lxml")
df = pd.concat(tables).to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Output:

[image]